How to understand that both the lim inf and lim sup of the sets of real numbers is either open or closed?
I am reading the Real Analyais (4th edition) by Royden, H. L., & Fitzpatrick, P. In Section 1.4, it is said that

both the lim inf and lim sup of a countable collection of sets of real numbers, each of which is either open or closed, are a Borel set.

I do not know how to obtain this result. The lim inf and lim sup of sets of real numbers are defined as follows.

Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a countable collection of sets that belong to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$. Define the sets
\begin{align*}
    \limsup  \{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} &= \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty} A_n \right) , \\ 
    \liminf  \{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} &= \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty} A_n \right) .
\end{align*}


The title suggests that you are misinterpreting the statement. It says that if all sets $A_n$ are open or closed, then $\limsup A_n$ and $\liminf A_n$ are Borel sets. This is easy if you know that Borel sets form a $\sigma$-algebra.

Thank you for the explanation.
